# Getting error while installing autocorrect in python 3.6 (Windows)

Tags: python

I need to use autocorrect package in my project to correct the misspelled words.
for example:

```
from autocorrect import spell
spell('gruop')
```

But while trying to install autocorrect in python 3.6 as mentioned in https://github.com/phatpiglet/autocorrect. Am getting error as shown below:

```
(py36) C:\Users\Shylashree\Documents>pip install autocorrect

Collecting autocorrect
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD1747C3C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/autocorrect/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD1747CBE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/autocorrect/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD1747CD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/autocorrect/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD1747C6A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/autocorrect/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD1747C7B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/autocorrect/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement autocorrect (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for autocorrect
```

Can anyone please tell me that how to sort out this error? and also suggest me is any other packages there to correct the misspelled words in python 3.6?

Comment: Did you try using `pip3`? like this `pip3 install autocorrect`.

Comment: Thanks Omar Einea for your reply. Yeah i tried but failed to install